# TYPO3 Newsletter Extension (Ext.newsletter) does not send Test-Newsletter?

Tags: php, typo3, newsletter, typo3-6.2.x

I try to initialize the Extension `newsletter`for `TYPO3 6.2.25` with `PHP 5.3.10`.
 **It's not `direct_mail`!** 
I'll try to use: [Ext.newsletter](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/newsletter).

The extension is very easy to use. No TypoScript is needed: [Documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/newsletter/). For testing, use a backend user to the recipient-list. I use an HTML-Template with tables, no javascript, inline-styles. Everything is fine, but it is not possible to send me a test newsletter.

I've got the info: "Newsletter was sent", but I won't get the newsletters at my e-mail client (tried several e-mail addresses ...).

It's hard to help, but maybe I've forgot sth. important?!
Thanks for reading ;) and I hope someone can help.

Maybe there's a server problem? But I'm not the server admin, so I don't know?!

screenshots:
[image: no error]
[image: php errors]

Comment: Does sending a test email from the install tool work? If not, check your email settings in the install tool.

Comment: Hi Jost. This was successful. The test mail from install tool works

Comment: Hi, I know it's hard to help for my individual problem ... I  think i'll use `Mailchimp` or `Ext.direct_mail`.   Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it.
My server administrator update the PHP-Version from `5.3.7`to `5.5.10`!

The dependencies for the [extension](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/newsletter) `newsletter`is:

- PHP (5.3.7)
- TYPO3 (6.1.0 - 7.99.99)
- scheduler (6.1.0

But `PHP 5.3.7` doesn't work, in my case! Now, with `PHP 5.5` it works out of the box!